# How to auto connect to vpn server if connection is down (VPN always on)

Tags: networking, server, vpn, openvpn

I have an openvpn connection with a `client.conf` file. I have set this to auto connect on startup however I would like to also make it reconnect if connection goes down. There does not seem to be a feature related to `openvpn` that does this. This make me question a couple of things:

1. Can connection be lost? i.e. `tun0` in `ifconfig` not exist? If so will I be connected to the internet without vpn or will the internet connection halt?
2. How can I set up my `openvpn` client for my linux machine to **always** be connected to the internet via a VPN. (I would rather have my internet connection lost than surf without VPN.

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.

Answer (score 1):

I added a VPN via Ubuntu network config GUI by doing a .openvpn file-import. Then ran the alternative network GUI `nm-connection-editor`

Select your wired connection (not your VPN) and press the cog icon. Then click the `General` tab and select `Automatically connect to VPN` and choose the VPN.

Now when the connection goes up it will automatically connect to the VPN. However, I am not 100% sure if there is any delay or window where non-VPN traffic can get through before the VPN is up. And for some reason when I boot or resume from suspend I have no network until I manually turn off the wired connection and then turn it back on again. But I never have a case where I am connected with no VPN.